# Checking params in url with Javascript to change button color

Tags: javascript, window.location

In my rails 6 app, i want to check the id of the params in the Url and change the button with the same id. E.G: http://localhost:3000/en/search?category=9, should change button with id="9"

My Buttons are like so:

```
 <div class="tooltip-wrap">
  <%= link_to request.params.merge(category: "9"), class: "button is-rounded", id: "9" do %>
  <i class="fas fa-thermometer-full"></i><%= (t "service.title").truncate(17) %>
  <% end %>                                      
  </div>
```

Javascript function

```
<script>
if (window.location.search.indexOf('category=' + "{n}") > -1){
$('#{n}').addClass('has-background-primary');
};
</script>
```

Url like:

```
http://localhost:3000/en/search?category=9
```

Comment: Is this page rendered with javascript? Why are you using javascript at all to do this? When the html.erb file is rendered, you can just set the button color then using `params[:category]`.

Comment: Because i have multiple buttons, so depending on the category, one button will change color

Comment: Right, so when creating the button, you just check if the category of the button matches `params[:category]` (the url parameter) and change the class/style accordingly.

Comment: could you explain please, i don't see how to do it

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it like this

```rb
<div class="tooltip-wrap">
  <%= link_to request.params.merge(category: "9"), class: "button is-rounded #{'color-class' if params[:category] == '9'}", id: "9" do %>
    <i class="fas fa-thermometer-full"></i><%= (t "service.title").truncate(17) %>
  <% end %>                                      
</div>
```

Much cleaner without relying on javascript to properly parse the url and find the parameter.

Seems like this is the best solution until they add the `class_names` helper in rails 6.1. See here: https://blog.bigbinary.com/2020/02/04/rails-6-1-introduces-class_names-helper.html

---

If you're manually writing out the code for each button like above, you could simplify this a lot by generating it dynamically from a hash in the controller. It has the benefit of being much easier to add/remove categories.

Controller:

```rb
@categories = [
               { id: '1', name: 'Category Name', icon: 'fas fa-thermometer-full' },
               { id: '2', name: 'Another Category', icon: 'fas fa-book' }
              ]
```

You could even declare that as a constant in an initializer to use across your entire application.

`.html.erb`

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <div class="tooltip-wrap">
    <%= link_to request.params.merge(category: category[:id]), class: "button is-rounded #{'color-class' if params[:category] == category[:id]}", id: category[:id] do %>
      <i class="<%= category[:icon] %>"></i><%= ("#{category[:name]}").truncate(17) %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

You're using a server-side language. Let it do some of the work for you.

Comment: thank you it works, but as i have 12 buttons, it is adding quite some code to the page, i still think something can be done with js